# Ping specific ethernet port with dual port network card

Tags: port, ping, ethernet

I have a dual port network adapter. So I have one NIC with two ports.
I am trying to verify both ports.
My idea was to ping over the two ports.
One network interface stands for one NIC, am I right? So both ports are communicating over the same network interface...

Now my question: 
How can I select the outgoing port when pinging?

I am using an Ubuntu distribution.

I wish you a nice start of the week

Answer (score -1):

Both ports represent separate, independent network interfaces, even if they sit on the same chip. Each NIC usually has its own IP address, so you just ping that.